# How to fix "The package org.neuroph.core is not accessible" in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, import, external

I would like to use the Neuroph Library to add a Neural Network to my application. How do I correctly include the library in my project, import it, and use it?

- I am new to Eclipse
- I've added it the necessary JARs as an external library to my project's build path.

```java
import org.neuroph.core.*;

public class ChatBotCore {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //No code regarding Neuroph work due to import issues.
    }

}
```

I expected the import to work correctly however I got "The package org.neuroph.core is not accessible"

Comment: Your import statement looks fine to me. The problem is probably with how the jar file is added in Eclipse. Are you 100% sure that it is on the build path? You can double check by looking for a "remove from build path" option when you right click on the jar in the package explorer.

Comment: @MichaelNoguera Yep, a "remove from build path" option is there.